# Shorthand css with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, shorthand

I am wondering about jQuery. I tried to change the border of a Div. It works well if I change the border step by step. However the shorthand CSS does not work.

An example:

```
// Works well
   $(div).css({
    'border-color': '#000000',
    'border-width': '10px'
    });

 // But this does not work:
$(div).css({
'border': '10px solid #000000'
});
```

Is there a way to use shorthand CSS styles or is this not supported?

Comment: It works: https://jsfiddle.net/w2uL7v3p/ - so you need to look somewhere else, like what is your div variable or if there are other factors.

Comment: This seems to be not totally supported: From jQuery API "although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.".

Comment: this API paragraph talks about retrieval. Getting such a value is, indeed, not guaranteed. But I never had a problem setting it, with your method or the one in the answer, it all comes down to a standard html's node .style property manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When utilizing [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) setting single property try setting without object notation

`$(div).css("border", "10px solid #000000");`